# C++, деструктор std::future

Tags: c++, исключения, деструктор, future

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
bool infinity()
{
  while (1)
  {
    int i = 1;
  }
  return true;
}

int main()
{
  try
  {
    future<bool> f = async(std::launch::async, infinity);
    throw 1;
  }
  catch (...)
  {
  }
  cout << "After catch" << endl;
}
```

В моем представлении здесь произойдет следующее:

- Фьючерс `f` ожидает результат функции `infinity`, которая запущена в фоновом режиме;
- Функция `infinity` не планирует завершаться;
- В том потоке, в котором находится фьючерс `f`, возникает исключение;
- Происходит вызов деструктора фьючерса `f`;
- Поток, в котором вызывается деструктор фьючерса `f`, блокируется.

То есть, я хочу понять, действительно ли деструктор фьючерса блокирует поток, в котором находится фьючерс, до тех пор, пока поток, результат которого нужен фьючерсу, не завершится (предоставит результат своего выполнения)?

Дело может быть не только в исключении, но и в обыкновенном выходе из пространства видимости, в котором находится объект-фьючерс.

Comment: https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/~future
https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async
возможно тут есть ответ

Comment: Ну вообще-то, насколько мне известно, да.